# Why need to add WITH RESULT SETS in OLE DB source activity in SSIS Package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I am getting error to add WITH RESULT SETS clause in OLE DB source activity in SSIS Package while calling Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2012 version 11.0.3000. I am getting this error only on dev server, the same package working fine on other servers. Previously these packages was also working fine on dev. After adding WITH RESULT SETS clause it works fine. Can some one tell me the reason behind it?

Regards,

Muhammad Kamal

Comment: Can you post the Stored Procedure you're calling, and the text of the SSIS SQL Task?

Comment: On the servers where it's working without the `WITH RESULTS SETS` specification, is the Connection Manger using the same release (2005/2008/2012/2014) as the dev server? An SSIS package could be running on 2012 and using a connection manager that connects to SQL Server 2005 so I want to understand the combination of affected servers